how do I get ADB EXCEPTIONS
I am a very young developer, I managed to develop a too that runs ADB commands, but my problem is, the tool run to the end and shows done as I instructed it. I have codes of disabling packages,my main issues is it doesn't display successfully and failed operations, it works silently. Please help
    public static string adb(string cmd)
    {
        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/adb/adb.exe",
                Arguments = cmd,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }// Start ADB server
    public bool Adbdevice()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (Form1.adb("devices").Contains("\tdevice"))
            flag = true;
        return flag;
    } // Check if device is connected in ADB mode


Add also, RedirectStandardError=true, then call process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(), and debug to investigate any errors in adb.exe execution.
